# Excel - Change bar graph to all same colour

Tags: excel, graph, charts

I have a bar graph as seen below, I need to change the colour of all the bars to let's say green.

Currently the only way I have been able to find to do this is click each individual date and then the fill bucket green as excel doesn't allow you to CTRL + Click multiple elements. Is there a way to change the colour of all the bars shown in one go?

Worth mentioning I can not change the colours by creating a "values table" as the workbook is locked and I have to do this for several different graphs.

[image: Excel Graph in 2 colours]

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because you have created the chart using every date as an individual serie. I suggest to use the "Switch Row/Column" option and became all the dates as a unique serie, so all the bars will have the same color.

In the other hand if you need to keep the chart as you shown on the picture shared, is possible to change every bar at once but just using a VBA code.